# Hiding php files from browser, but calling them from flash?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript

I have a flash app on my website that calls certain php scripts on the server.

For example, I have a script that gets all items owned by the user of my flash game. The script returns a JSON encoded response consisting of a return code and a return message (the message in this case is an array of items). I call the php script from actionscript as follows:

```
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("mysite.com/getItems.php");
urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onResponse);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, networkError);
loader.load(urlReq);
```

However, one could also easily just navigate to `mysite.com/getItems.php` in their browser and they would see, providing they had an alive session, the JSON response right there in the browser. It makes me fairly uncomfortable considering it shows the format of my underlining transfer protocol.

Is there any way of 'hiding' my php scripts from direct browser access, whilst still having the script available when called from actionscript.

Comment: What problems would arise if the user could see the JSON response or the format of your transfer protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to include a key as a GET parameter for the request in your app. Then in the php page, you only output the JSON if the value of `$_GET['key']` is valid.

Someone watching the traffic of your app would be able to extract this and use it in their browser for direct access, but a user advanced enough for that is likely to already see your JSON in their view of the app's traffic.

You could extend things further and check the various client information reported to PHP via [`get_browser()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) or [`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) but, once again, a skilled user would be able to overcome this check.

Comment: Indeed.  The key thing to remember is that anything your Flash program does, an attacker can also do.

Answer (score 3):

In short, no.  If one program running on the user's computer can access your site's API, so can another.  You can try to use encryption or cookie/key techniques, but all of these can be broken by someone dedicated enough.

- Encryption can be defeated by disassembling/decompiling the Flash binary.
- Cookie/key techniques can generally be defeated very easily by using a packet sniffer, such as [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org).  (Using HTTPS could render this approach ineffective, but disassembling the Flash binary would be sufficient to work around the use of HTTPS.)

I'd consider having an API, even an undocumented one, to be rather useful to coder-types who play your game.

Comment: +1 with API. Whether it's web development or game development (browser or otherwise), you can never trust the client. Game example: FPS shooter, you shoot the enemy, blood appears, they don't take damage, why? Latency. The client decided you hit the target and acted accordingly, however, the server doesn't trust your client and knows that you missed. This is to prevent us doing things like this from the client-side: `while ($player = getPlayer()) { tellServerWeKilled($player); }`